# Padding issue in IE7

Tags: css

I have been struggling to find out why IE7 is taking more space in padding while other browsers not.

If someone knows how to do that than please do share.

Comment: Please post code and/or a link to the page

Answer (score 4):

The browsers naturally default to different padding/margin settings.  Adding on top of this, browsers treat width differently as well.

You may want to consider resetting element styling so that it's reasonably consistent across browsers.  See http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ for an example.

Comment: An essential first step to cross browser compatibility. +1